# What does うち農家 mean?

Tags: words, compounds

> うち農家で兄弟も多いからオレが料理することが多かったんだ

Is 農家 normally used for just one person, a family or a place?

If it means "farmhouse" in this sentence, then I think うち could mean "home" and it could be used by the character to make the listener understand that the farmhouse was his home, he invents the word "home-farmhouse"/"farmhouse-home"/"farmhome".

Or is it 内 used as an adverb and it means "internally"? But I've always seen it used as a noun.

Comment: うち（は）農家で兄弟も多いから〜

Comment: Here うち means "my *family*".

Comment: @naruto 農家 means a place then, "farmhouse", not "farmer" or "farm family"/"family of farmers", right?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi 農家 is not a place but a type of a family. "My family is a farm family" may seem redundant, but remember that うち is a term that vaguely refers to "I", "we", "my family", "my company", "my school" and so on depending on the context. You can think of it as "We are a farm family", too.

Comment: @naruto Ah! で = です! I didn't think about it, I thought it was the particle.